# How do I clear my floats?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;}
*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
.wrap{float:left;width:100%;background-color:#ccc;}
.content{width:1000px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#efefef;}
.left{float:left;width:760px;}
.right{float:left;width:240px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            111<br />
            222<br />
            <!-- there still have some lines -->
        </div>
        <div class="right">         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The DIV height is zero, the background color has disappeared. Even if I give `DIV.content height auto or 100%`. Why is the background color gone?

Comment: The question is "How do I clear my floats?" which is *surely* a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `overflow:auto` for `.content` to clear the floats

example: http://jsbin.com/onedi3

More information for clearing you can find at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `.content {}` will sort this out. It's a float clearing thing. Adding overflow or a clearing element will make the wrapper contain what's inside.

Answer (score 1):

Floating elements are "removed" from their parent, layout-wise. So your content div is empty and gets a height of 0. See [this css-discuss article](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Clearing_Space) for the causes and fixes.

Answer (score 0):

With XHTML the div has to have content or it will not be registered as "there." To force it to display using XHTML, type `&nbsp;` in the div you wish to display.