# better float clearing

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I clear my floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969942/how-do-i-clear-my-floats)

is there any way to clear floats better than clear div?

currently i'm using a div to clear floats like

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: @asya check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266667/hr-clear-vs-div-clear-which-is-better/5266729#5266729

Comment: @Sotiris You would be best to post it as an answer so the asker can mark the question as "answered" :)

Comment: @Myles it's duplicate so the best is to close it I think

Comment: @MylesGray: No, that would be a dupe.

Comment: @Sotiris Right you are - can close yet.. need another 200

Comment: thank you sotiris. can i remove this question myself or need to wait moderators.

Comment: @asya Do not delete the question. Wait for it to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative suggestion, you could not use floats at all...

I've found that virtually everything that I would floats to do, I've been able to achieve just as well using `display:inline-block;`, and without having to mess around with clearing the floats.

I know it's a slightly left-field answer, but it's worth considering.

`inline-block` does have a few quirks of its own, but I hope you'll give it a try. (Oh, and it does have some bugs in IE6 which may put you off if you need to support that browser... they can be worked around, but if you're supporting IE6 then you have enough other problems to worry about anyway)

Comment: Yeah, that whole browser support issue presents a problem in this case.  I know IE6 usage percentage is in single digits by now, but (especially in the corporate environment) you often have to support that old POS, either for your own internal network or the client's.

Comment: @Kon - even in IE6, the problem can be worked around (you just have to use `<span>` instead of `<div>`, because IE6 only allows `inline-block` on elements with a default style of `inline`... weird bug, but it can be stepped around)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of [clearfix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html)?  That way you only have to specify the class name:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: @Kon What's wrong with `overflow:auto`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it - I use it all the time.  Just not to clear floated content.  :)  Also, one major point of my answer is that there's no embedded styling in the markup, which is good practice to separate.

Comment: Because I'm awesome. Just kidding..  I don't know, I've used clearfix for quite a few years.  I know the overflow solution you're talking about, but just happen to have used it.  Perhaps I should revisit.

Comment: never* happen to have used it.

Comment: @Kon Yes, check it out. overflow:auto/hidden is clearly superior.

Answer (score 0):

I like `<br />` for clearing floats, and in CSS, just add some classes:

```
br.left { clear: left; }
br.right { clear: right; }
br.both { clear: both; }
```

Works like a charm, and easy to implement - `<br class="left" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need clearfix divs at all.

you should use `overflow:auto;`

http://jsfiddle.net/HharD/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container {width:200px;background:#faf;min-height:10px;overflow:auto;}
#left {width:100px;background:#fa0;float:left;height:100px;}
#right{width:100px;background:#09f;float:left;height:110px;}
```