# css issue floating boxes within their father

Tags: css, html

I want to have little news boxes inside a content box, I want them to make lines and colums, how much of them... I don't know it will depend on the screen size to see how many.

I've created the boxes and it's father but the problem is, despite that they float left just as I desire (in fact the idea is completed...) but the father doesn't grow as they form rows.
the columns are ready to go...
but unfortunalety vertical stuff in css is always difficult to me...

look this is want to achieve for "N" news boxes:

[layout http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8058/derpqr.jpg](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/8058/derpqr.jpg)

here the code I've got right now, the red border is just for the wrapper identificacion...

http://jsbin.com/orojik/3

Comment: so you want the red bordered element to grow with the inner boxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clear my floats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969942/how-do-i-clear-my-floats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get the container to grow with the content....

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>` should be added just after the inner content but in the container `#cuerpo`

[see here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/8xhMg/1/) Please tell me if i'm way off with this answer... i'll revise. (I think this was your question??)

Comment: sorry for the crappy engrish.
yes this was a perfect answer, now I have a second answer for you my friend...
can you point to some CSS3 literature where I can learn more about this?, I always have troubles with this kind of thing.

Comment: you can always check out the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css3/info) for good information.

Answer (score 2):

give the div with id='cuerpo' overflow: hidden;

http://gtwebdev.com/workshop/floats/enclosing-floats.php

Comment: Your answer is right but it's better if you explain why this happen & this is not a good way give an answer

Comment: @sandeep I gave a link reference, they can read all they want. my question is why did he come here and not google?

Comment: sorry for "not doing my homework, but I always as much as I could... but here I wasn't getting anywhere... I just blame my lack of english knowledge... I failed to look for enclosing, truly never heard the word before...
anyways thx for the info

Comment: @Marcos Vargas Moran don't worry about it, you learn as you go. Things like that are hard to find when you don't know what to search for

Comment: sorry for writing too much xD, but I'm amazed with you... here where I live I have no one to ask this kind of question, so I need to come to sites such as this :D.
I really didn't know that overflow can be used like that, I just had use it for the scrollbars and some lil' image manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your div

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content:"\0020"; display:block; height:0; visibility:hidden; } .clearfix:after { clear:both; }
```

add that CSS and and change the html

```
<div id="cuerpo" class="ui-widget-content clearfix">
```

If you cannot change the html do this

add a class at the end of the floats

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...
now I need to learn about clear property... never heard of it before.